# Column Data in CSV file to h5 format

Tags: python, pandas, csv, hdf5

I am trying to convert a CSV file to h5 format file.

I have gone through multiple posts and I have been able to create the h5 file but still unable to pull individual columns from the CSV file and add them to the h5 file, please let me know if there is any solution to this.

Essentially I have four columns in my CSV file with 4000 observations in each column, trying to check if there is any way to directly convert it to h5 or pull individual column data and edit the existing h5 file. Thank you.

```
import pandas as pd

filename = '/home/test3.h5'

df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 2], [4, 5]]),
                   columns=['a', 'b'])

print(pd.read_hdf(filename, 'data'))
```

Answer (score 0):

As specified in the [pandas I/O guide, section HDF5 (PyTables)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.2.0/user_guide/io.html#hdf5-pytables), there are 2 simple functions to store as hdf:

- [`pd.to_hdf`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.2.0/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_hdf.html)
- [`pd.read_hdf`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.2.0/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.read_hdf.html)

So converting a csv to h5 could be as simple as:

```py
df = pd.read_csv('input_file.csv')
df.to_hdf('output_file.h5', 'data')
```

If you want to combine the data

```py
df1 = pd.read_csv('input_file.csv')
df2 = pd.read_hdf('input_file.h5', 'data')
save = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=[...]) # combine data
save.to_hdf('output_file.h5', 'data')
```

If `input_file.h5` and `output_file.h5` are the same, `mode='w'` allows to overwrite the file, using different keys with `mode='a'` (by default) allows to append to the file, `append=True` allows to append to the dataframe inside the file, etc.

The guide I linked contains a lot more examples of how to use these tools and also the `pd.HDFStore` which allows to open the whole file and look into the keys it contains, I suggest you give it a thorough read.

Comment: My pleasure @user13069536 ! You can upvote the answer with the up arrow next to it if it’s useful, and if it solved your problem you can tick the checkmark next to it. See [this help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) on how the site works with respect to answers you receive

Comment: Yes, I tried but I need 15 reputation points to upvote, I will do it once I earn those points. Thank you.